# How to avoid Parent Directory Link when listing the files of a Directory?

Tags: php

I used the following code to display the contents of a Folder say images (Both Directories as well as Files in that folder)

```
<?php

$dir="images/"; // Directory where files are stored

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
{
    $newvar1="$dir$filename";// For Hyperlink Path
?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $newvar1; ?>"><?php echo $filename;
?></a></p>
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}

?>
```

But the PHP file shows an output with two additional Links

1. A link to the folder 'images' and
2. A Link to the 'Homepage'.

I tried to filter those two links with "filesize" function but getting some error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: while showing all those links, check specifically for dir names with `.` and `..`, and ignore if you find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip current dir and parent dir with a check.

```
while(...) {
   if($filename == ".." || $filename == ".") continue;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to something like this:

```
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
{
    if($filename != '.' || $filename != '..')  // This part to check and ignore
        $newvar1="$dir$filename";// For Hyperlink Path
    else
        continue;   //while loop will no further be processed!
//...
}
```

Comment: `else continue` is useless in this case (and if you see how ugly the code is (not your code, the Php code of Surya), you can push on a bit further the ugly way and remove `else continue`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a more in-depth answer and I'm so fed up with such things... This is absolutely an horrible piece of code, *even though Php does permit* such horrible things.

Something like this is easier to read, easier to maintain, and easier to debug:

```
<?php

$tab = array();
$dir="images/"; // Directory to parse
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
    {
        if($filename != ".." && $filename != ".")
        {
            $tab[$filename] = $dir.$filename; // Hyperlink Path
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_list);
}

/* Display separated from logic */
foreach ($tab as $filename => $hyperlink)
{
    echo '<p><a href="'.$hyperlink.'">'.$filename.'</a></p>';
}

?>
```

More compact but a bit less easy to read:

```
<?php

$tab = array();
$dir="images/"; // Directory to parse
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
        if($filename != ".." && $filename != ".") {
            $tab[$filename] = $dir.$filename; // Hyperlink Path
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_list);
}

/* Display separated from logic */
foreach ($tab as $filename => $hyperlink) {
    echo '<p><a href="'.$hyperlink.'">'.$filename.'</a></p>';
}

?>
```

---

And some people (including my old teachers) tell that "if there's one line of code, don't use `{}`" (**which I strongly disagree because it may lead to errors later on**) but here's the "optimized" version:

```
<?php

$tab = array();
$dir="images/";
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
        if($filename != ".." && $filename != ".")
            $tab[$filename] = $dir.$filename; // Hyperlink Path
    closedir($dir_list);
}

foreach ($tab as $filename => $hyperlink)
    echo '<p><a href="'.$hyperlink.'">'.$filename.'</a></p>';

?>
```

Comment: Removing braces, can sometimes make your code confusing, and at some point of time, you often realize that you need some multiple statements, and then you will have the need to adding up braces again. For now, my code was about coding simplicity, and not winning a coding beauty contest!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm telling almost everyday to my students!! I just wanted to show what it could be done so that, if one day someone reads a code like that, he/she will understand it.